# Assistance needed with Google Maps integration in ASP.NET CORE MVC

Tags: google-maps, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a SQL table of incidents with columns for Lat and Long. I need a map to show the location of all incidents.

SQL Database Table: Incident
Controller: MapController.cs
View: Map/Index.cshtml

Code I am currently using is below. A map shows up, but there are no markers and no errors in the console.

Controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Conversion.Models;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
namespace Conversion.Controllers
{
    public class MapController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IncidentContext _context;
        public MapController(IncidentContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var cities = new List<Incident>();
            return View(cities);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetAnswer(string question)
        {
            int index = _rnd.Next(_db.Count);
            var answer = _db[index];
            return Json(answer);
        }
        private static readonly Random _rnd = new Random();
        private static readonly List<string> _db = new List<string> { "Yes", "No", "Definitely, yes", "I don't know", "Looks like, yes" };
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Conversion.Models.Incident>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Map";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/AdminLTE/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=GOOGLE/API/KEY"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #map_canvas {
            height: 650px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<script>
    var cities = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@Model));
    //console.log(cities);


    $(document).ready(function() {
        // execute
        (function() {
            // map options
            var options = {
                zoom: 5,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.4515, -91.1871),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
                mapTypeControl: false
            };
            // init map
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), options);

            for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
                // init markers
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(cities[i].Lat, cities[i].Long),
                    map: map,
                    title: cities[i].Address
                });
                // process multiple info windows
                (function(marker, i) {
                    // add click event
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                            content: cities[i].Address
                        });
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                })(marker, i);
            }
        })();
    });
</script>
```

Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
namespace Conversion.Models
{
    public partial class Incident
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("IncidentID")]
        public long IncidentId { get; set; }
        [StringLength(40)]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Longitude { get; set; }
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Latitude { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(8, 6)")]
        public decimal? Lat { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(9, 6)")]
        public decimal? Long { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Steven, if the solution did help achieve the requirement, you can accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I need a map to show the location of all incidents.

If you check the actual data of `cities` on browser side, you would find it might look like below.

[image]

In your JavaScript code of adding marker on map, you are using `cities[i].Lat` and `cities[i].Long` to set the position, which seems cause the issue.

You can try to use `lat`, `long` and `address` to get data from json object, like below.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(cities[i].lat, cities[i].long),
    map: map,
    title: cities[i].address
});
// process multiple info windows
(function (marker, i) {
    // add click event
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: cities[i].address
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
})(marker, i);
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: I changed "Lat" / "Long" to "lat" / "long", but I am still getting the same result. Also, I can't find the browser-side data as you did.

Comment: `can't find the browser-side data as you did` Please debug your code and check if any items in `cities` list, it seems that you are passing null list to your view.